# Fire form submit event from custom component

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the latest Ember (3.2).
I have made extension of **text-area** component:
app/components/enterable-textarea.js

```
export default TextArea.extend({
    keyPress(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            console.info('e ', event);
        }
      }
});
```

I see the debug output in the console once I hit the 'Enter' key.

In my route template I have simple form like:

```
    <form {{action "save" model.newNote on='submit'}}>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tag">Tag</label>
        {{input type="text" value=model.newNote.tag 
placeholder="#anytag" class="form-control"}}
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="note">Notepad</label>
        {{enterable-textarea value=model.newNote.note 
rows="6" class="form-control"}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Ho do I pass form action to the component or fire the 'submit' event of the form?
I need to pass whole form to the route action by pressing the 'Enter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an action as a property and then call it as a function:

```
export default TextArea.extend({
    onEnter: () => {}, //or function() {},
    keyPress(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.get('onEnter')(); //or even this.onEnter();
        }
      }
});

{{enterable-textarea value=model.newNote.note 
    rows="6" class="form-control" onEnter=(action "save" model.newNote)}}
```

[Read more about actions](https://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-closure-actions/)

Comment: I tried it before, but got the error "Error: Assertion Failed: An action named 'save' was not found in (generated roll controller)"
So do I need to implement controller fro that?
I have a just router

Comment: @Paul in this case your submit button shouldn't work either

Comment: I definitely want to have both options the button submit and keyboard submit )). 
According to article below the controllers are useful for model decoration (for adding computed properties) there is no sense to have the controller in this case, correct me if I'm wrong.
https://dockyard.com/blog/2017/06/16/ember-best-practices-what-are-controllers-good-for

Comment: @Paul error mentioned above means that you don't have an action with name "save" defined. In this case I have no idea how you form could work at all. Where did you define your action?

Comment: of course I have a action )) 
`export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return RSVP.hash({
            .....
        });
    },
    actions: {        
        save: function(submitData) {
            ......
        }
    }    
    
});`

Comment: @Paul you have two options: define action on controller instead of route or use [route-action helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper).

Comment: @Paul Also, avoiding using controllers _by any cost_ is not a best practice but pointless fight against framework. If you read that article carefully, you will notice these lines: "_The same principle goes for actions: put all the actions that update the Model on the Controller, no need to use ember-route-action-helper for that._".

Comment: yeah I see. I'm not planning to use **ember-route-action-helper** coz is not _Ember like_ solution. I've been using controller once I was reading parameters from query string. I'll add the controller to solve my issue, but I still don't understand why I need controller action in this case. What is the point?

Comment: @Paul That's just how things work at the moment - you need controller to pass actions to components on corresponding page. It's like that for a long time - each page consists of template and controller, and if in template we write `{{foo}}`, that means `controller.foo`. As far as I know, it was planned to get rid of controllers but for now they are still here and we still need them. As workaround, you can create a component for the whole page and have actions defined in that component but there is no point in that.

Comment: Make sense. Unfortunately the roles of controller and router is not so explicit than in pure MVC architecture